# C++ - Name/Access Class with char variable

Tags: c++, class, cin

I'm relative new to C++ and I'm sure there is probably plenty on information on here. Unfortunately, I don't seem to understand it.

I have a class called Account with variables called Number and Balance. The Member Name is given by the User through cin and represent an Account Number. I was able to dynamically create an object through cin. and give their variables a value through cin. However, I'm not able to give the variables a value or ask for the values in the class through cin.

I have been looking for hours and just cannot figure it out. Any help is appreciated. Thanks guys.

Here is my code:

```
class Account {   
public:   
            int Number;   
        int Balance;   
};

int main() {   
        int Nmbr;    
        int Bal;    
        cin >> Nmbr;    
        cin >> Bal;   

        Account Nmbr; // create the object   
        Nmbr.Number = Nmbr; // add the cin input 'Nmbr' to the variable Number - FALSE  
        Nmbr.Balance = Bal; // add the cin input 'Bal' to the variable Balance - FALSE  

        cout << Nmbr.Number << endl; // display Account.Number - FALSE  
        cout << Nmbr.Balance << endl; //display Account.balance - FALSE  
}
```

Comment: You can't use same name (Nmbr) more than once.

Comment: Are you sure it compiles? (You redefine typename Nmbr.)

Comment: Line 15: error: conflicting declaration 'Account Nmbr'

Comment: Thanks for your answers. No, it doesn't compile. Whenever I use Nmbr, it gives me the following error: expression must have class type. How do I get to it to call the object what the user defines in cin then? Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

Ok I think something like this is what you are after:

account.h:

```
class Account
{
public:
    Account();
    Account(int number);
    int Number;
    int Balance;
};
```

account.cpp:

```
#include "account.h"
Account::Account() {}
Account::Account(int number) {
    this->Number = number;
}
```

So then in main you would do something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "account.h"
#include <vector>

const size_t MAXNUM = 5;

int main()
{
    std::vector<Account*> allAccounts;

    for (int accntNumber = 0; accntNumber < MAXNUM; accntNumber++) {
        Account* account = new Account(accntNumber);
        allAccounts.push_back(account);
    }

    // Then later do other stuff:
    for (int accntNumber = 0; accntNumber < MAXNUM; accntNumber++) {
        Account* checkAccount = allAccounts.at(accntNumber);
        std::cout << "Account # = " << checkAccount->Number << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Edit: added an account class with a class creator based on the account number.

Comment: Thanks but I don't think it works for me. I guess it's just me but how is Nmbr connected to the Account object name? Thanks

Comment: Nmbr should not be connected to the Account object name, you have declared it as an int to hold a value that you later assign to the Account object instance variable Number.

Comment: ok let's say the user inputs 222 for the Nmbr and 300 for the Bal. I then create an object Account 222. Then I want to say 222.Number = 222 and 222.Balance = 300. How can I do that without connecting the Nmbr and Bal to the object?

Comment: I guess I don't understand, why would you ever want to do that?

Comment: Because the User needs to input several different Numbers, so the object will be created through cin input. And since I won't know the Number beforehand, I need Nmbr and Bal be linked. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: Why don't you create a constructor for the Account object, something like: Account: Account::Account(int number)
{
    this->Number = number;
}

Comment: I didn't know about this functionality. It looks like it may work for me. Thanks again roybatty

Comment: So I added this line: Account::Number(Nmbr) {this->Number = Nmbr}. However, for the first Number it gave me the following error: a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object. What did I do wrong this time?

Comment: Thanks again for your help. Unfortunately, I have to go now. But your input was very helpful and I will try it for sure. It seems like way beyond what I have learned so far but hopefully I get it to work.